# how to get multiple items from array of Mongo ObjectIDs

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, react-native, nosql

I have a long array of MongoDB ObjectIds but only keys ..

```
var list=['5edca3a1952997473c5beadd',....50 more]
```

I need to search these in a database but is only possible if I append ObjectId(key) which I am unable to do. Is there any method through which I can search in database without modifying keys.

Array size can go upto 1000s so can't do it manually.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Can you share a few examples to explain it in a better way?

Comment: I am creating a watchlist of movies. I have two database-movies and users->saved. When a user clicks on save,the object id of movie is appended in saved array of user db.Only the key(`'73t4q87tfujbarejb'`). Finally, when open the watchlist page, the API first gets the saved array and then I have to search them in  movies database but it is only possible if my query is `ObjectId('gfuveuwvcj4r') `.I can't do it manually because of dymanic array

Comment: do you need mongoDB aggregate Query?

Comment: if you want to do dynamicly objectId in database then try this idea..
before search you need to convert that in objectId 
pls check this link ->
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/
i hope its useful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to search by ids but can't do so because they're not ObjectIds yet. You will need to map over them one by one and return an objectId instead.
If you use node.js:

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
const list = ['5edca3a1952997473c5beadd']; // The array with all the ids
const ids = list.map(id => new ObjectId(id))

// db.your_collection_name.find({ _id: { $in: ids } }); // Mongo query.
```

Though I'm not sure if this is what you meant, the question is confusing.

Comment: Alternatively, we can run a loop and assign each value as: `a[i]=ObjectId(a[i])`